# Issue with iOS web app trying to launch YouTube app

Tags: ios, video, youtube, iphone-standalone-web-app

[My website](http://www.mtscollective.com) also runs as a web app when saved to the home screen on iOS and Android, but for some reason, any embedded YouTube video prompts to launch the YouTube app instead of the normal inline-to-fullscreen behaviour you'd expect in Safari. There's nothing special about how I'm embedding the videos--just using the code that YouTube gives. This never happened when I first set it up on iOS 8.

[This guy](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/page-wants-to-pop-open-youtube-app-on-ios-webapp#post-7356474) suggested it's an issue with the videos not playing inline, but I'm not sure how to fix this outside of this WordPress plug-in. I've looked around, but can't find anything.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

this happens because of iframe (probably) you are using, so the best way to avoid it is display video thumbnail image and some 'play' icon. then on click you will embed actual youtube iframe code. this also will allow you to save some traffic for mobile users.

as for thumbnails they can be usually requested by video id, like:

`'//img.youtube.com/vi/' + videoid + '/hqdefault.jpg'`

also you can try to detect if the app is in homescreen mode

`"standalone" in window.navigator && !window.navigator.standalone`

to load usual iframe mode if the app is not

Comment: I have a similar situation.  This answer allows my webapp to load and show the thumbnails.  However, when the user clicks on a thumbnail and the code loads the iframe, the user is prompted "Web wants to open YouTube" with an Open and Cancel button.  If the user hits Cancel, the video is not played and the thumbnail is gone (replaced by the iframe) leaving a whitespace where the video should be.  Any way to have the video play in the webapp??